# Redirect to login page after reset password in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and auth to login,register,password reset functionality everything works fine when i try to reset password it send an email and change the password works good .. After change the new password it redirect me to home page and it gets login automatically but what i want is after change the password redirect me to login page so that use can check the changed password is working correct or not..

So my question how to acheive this ???

and my ResetPasswordController is

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\ResetsPasswords;

class ResetPasswordController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Password Reset Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller is responsible for handling password reset requests
    | and uses a simple trait to include this behavior. You're free to
    | explore this trait and override any methods you wish to tweak.
    |
    */

    use ResetsPasswords;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after resetting their password.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }
}
```

when i try to change the $redirect to variable as login it throw me an error that page is not working.....I am just in confused state please helpme out

Answer (score 8):

You need to following changes in `ResetPasswordController` located at `app/Http/Controllers/Auth.`

Change the redirect path to your login page.

```
protected $redirectTo = '/login';
```

Override the resetPassword method to prevent user being logged in. Add this to the controller.

```
protected function resetPassword($user, $password)
{
    $user->forceFill([
        'password' => bcrypt($password),
        'remember_token' => Str::random(60),
    ])->save();
}
```

Use `use Illuminate\Support\Str;` at the top.

To send a custom response on redirection you can override `sendResetResponse` in your controller and add any custom session/flash messages. By default laravel sets its own response on successful password reset.

```
protected function sendResetResponse($response)
{
    return redirect($this->redirectPath())
                        ->with('status', trans($response));
}
```